# MySQL Left Join Not Working

Tags: mysql

I am trying to just select data from table agency where that agency has entry in the commission table with a certain carrier. My SQL query is returning all entries and 3 times. What am I doing wrong.

```
$allquery = mysql_query("SELECT agency.ID, agency.agencyname, agency.contdate, agency.physcity FROM agency LEFT JOIN commission ON commission.repnum = agency.repid WHERE agency.repid = '$repid' AND commission.repnum = '$repid' AND commission.carrier = 'Carrier' ")or die(mysql_error())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not joining two tables unless you actually specify a join criteria involving columns from each table.

```
SELECT agency.ID, agency.agencyname, agency.contdate, agency.physcity 
FROM agency LEFT JOIN commission ON commision.repid = agency.repid AND commission.carrier = 'Carrier'
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I dont know what I am doing, I edited above and its still retrieving all entries and 3 times each. It like its ignoring my WHERE clause. Tried a left and inner join.

Comment: Nevermind. I got it. Needed to do an ON commission.agencyid = agency.ID. I am tired. +1

Comment: But there is no reason for you to be specifying AND commission.repnum = '$repid'.  Since it's not clear what your table structure or data is, we can only guess at this point.  With that said, a left outer join returns all rows.  The property of the left join is that you will get a row for every row in the "left" table, which the table to the left of the "LEFT JOIN" clause.  In this case, that is agency.  Regardless of whether or not a matching row can be found in commision, you will get a row.

Comment: @gview Thank you!  Been stuck on a similar issue for several weeks and was finally able to resolve it thanks to your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Q: Why don't you use an inner join if you want to refer to elements in "commission"?

Q: Why are you doing a join at all???  I don't see how "commission" is linked to "agency".  Does "commission" have a "repid" field, too?

Anyway, based on what you've shown, I'd recommend this:

```
SELECT ID, agencyname, contdate, physcity 
FROM agency 
where repid = '$repid'
```